# Code simplification. Between positive and negative conditions

Tags: python

I have a question, how to simplify this code? I have the impression that it can be done in 3 conditional instructions and not in 6 ...

```
if (PID > 10 and self.last_pid > 0):
    if (PID >= self.last_pid):
            self.setKp(self.Kp+self.increase_val)
            self.increase_val = self.increase_val*2
    else:
        percent_last = PID/self.last_pid*100
        self.increase_val + (percent_last/100*self.increase_val)
        self.setKp(self.Kp+self.increase_val)


if (PID < -10 and self.last_pid < 0):
    if (PID <= self.last_pid):
            self.setKp(self.Kp+self.increase_val)
            self.increase_val = self.increase_val*2
    else:
        percent_last = PID/self.last_pid*100
        self.increase_val + (percent_last/100*self.increase_val)
        self.setKp(self.Kp+self.increase_val)
```

(Which might be simplified to:)

```
if A > 10 and B > 0:
    if A >= B:
        # do block A
    else:
        # do block B

if A < -10 and B < 0:
    if A <= B):
        # do block A
    else:
        # do block B
```

Comment: @zabop That may go a bit far; you obscure which "do stuff" is the same, and the numeric values in the condition may also matter. Also, `self.last_pid < 0` is not `not (self.last_pid > 0)`

Comment: Yes, that's good point... Would appreciate if you could give it an edit!

Comment: Could you please check whether my "simplification" is still correct, or if I missed some difference? Also, I don't think the conditions can be simplified / shortened. But (if this really is the case) you should add a comment that the code blocks are the same, or use two functions for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit long, but it takes less lines:

```
if (A > 10 and B > 10 and A>=B) or (A < -10 and B < 0 and A<= B):
  #do block a
else:
  #do block b
```

If you don't like it being so long, I would recommend turning each side of the `or` on the first line into a boolean variable and then using said variable in the `if` statement. Like so:

```
condA = A > 10 and B > 10 and A>=B
condB = A < -10 and B < 0 and A<= B
if condA or condB:
  #do block a
else:
  #do block b
```

Comment: No, this is not the same! For instance, if `A = 0`, then neither of the code blocks should be executed.

Answer (score 3):

This should be equivalent to your two cases for positive and negative values:

```
if abs(A) > 10 and A * B > 0:
    if abs(A) >= abs(B):
        # do block A
    else:
        # do block B
```

Explanation:

- `abs(A)` corresponds to `A > 10` and `A < -10` respectively
- `A * B > 0` means that both have the same sign and `B != 0`
- `abs(A) >= abs(B)` means `A <= B` if both are `< 0` and `A => B` if both are `> 0`

Now that's shorter and less repetitive, but whether it's easier to understand is for you to decide. In any case, you should add a comment explaining the code and that it is supposed to do.

With your original variables and procedures, this would be:

```
if abs(PID) > 10 and PID * self.last_pid > 0:
    if abs(PID) >= abs(self.last_pid):
        self.setKp(self.Kp+self.increase_val)
        self.increase_val = self.increase_val*2
    else:
        percent_last = PID/self.last_pid*100
        self.increase_val + (percent_last/100*self.increase_val)
        self.setKp(self.Kp+self.increase_val)
```

Some more points that I just noticed:

- your line `self.increase_val + (percent_last / 100 * self.increase_val)` does not do anything. I guess the `+` should be `=` or `+=`?
- it is kind of pointless to first `* 100` to get percent just to then `/ 100` again
- it's odd how in one case you add `increase_val` to `KP` *before* increasing it, but *after* increasing it in the other case; is this intentional?

In fact, I *think* that this could be further simplified to this, provided that the inner `if` is used to cap the increase to the `increase_val`; not sure whether it should be added to `Kp` before or after being increased itself, though, or if that should actually depend on the case.

```
if abs(PID) > 10 and PID * self.last_pid > 0:
    self.setKp(self.Kp + self.increase_val)
    self.increase_val *= 1 + min(PID/self.last_pid, 1)
```